# volume of Tetrahedron If equations of all faces are given

Tags: geometry, vector-analysis, volume

> A Tetrahedron $ABCD$ having its face $ABD,BCD$
>
> $CDA,ABC$ parallel to the plane $x+y=2,y+z=2,$
>
> $z+x=2,x+y+z=4$ respectively.
>
> If $AB=AC=\sqrt{2},AD=\sqrt{3}$ unit.
>
> Then volume of Tetrahedron in cubic unit is

what i try

solving

$\left.\begin{matrix}
x+y=2 & \\ 
x+y+z=4 & 
\end{matrix}\right\}\Rightarrow z=2$

$\left.\begin{matrix}
y+z=2 & \\ 
x+y+z=4 & 
\end{matrix}\right\}\Rightarrow x=2$

$\left.\begin{matrix}
x+z=2 & \\ 
x+y+z=4 & 
\end{matrix}\right\}\Rightarrow y=2$

Let position vector of point $D(\vec{0}),A(\vec{a}),B(\vec{b}),C(\vec{c})$

Then volume of Tetrahedron whose edges are $\vec{a},\vec{b},\vec{c}$ is

$$\frac{1}{6}\bigg|[\vec{a}\vec{b}\vec{c}]\bigg|\;\text{cubic unit}$$

How do i solve it Help me please

Comment: Note that the text only says the faces are parallel to the given planes, not that the faces lie in these planes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us first recall that a plane with equation $ux+vy+wz=h$ has the vector with coordinates $(u,v,w)$ as its normal vector.

Consider figure below (coordinates of the vectors normal to the different faces are obtained from your equations):

[image]

*Fig. 1 : The names of normal vectors have been attributed accordingly to the name of the opposite vertex. Please note that the orientation of these normals (inward/outward) is not necessarily the good one.*

As a consequence :

$$\vec{AB}= \alpha \ c \times d= \alpha \ \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \vec{AC}= \beta \ d \times b=\beta \ \begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}, \ \ \vec{AD}= \gamma \ b \times c=\gamma \ \begin{pmatrix}1\\-1\\1\end{pmatrix}, \ \ $$

(we can take normalization constants  $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=1$ : we are fortunate they  are in agreement with the length values $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ !).

Therefore, the volume of the tetrahedron is given by :

$$V= \dfrac16 \left|\begin{array}{rrr} 1&1&1\\-1&0&-1\\0&-1&1\end{array}\right|=\dfrac16$$

Comment: Pleas note that I have taken $A$ as the origin ; taking $D$ as the origin leads to a deadend : for example, obtaining $\vec{BD}$ in this way is impossible because we have no information about its norm (=length).